# Jetpack Compose X.dp performance issue?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Does using x.dp for example `1.dp` in every `@Composable()` cause performance issue?
As it creates a new object everytime?

```
@Stable
inline val Int.dp: Dp get() = Dp(value = this.toFloat())
```

Will it be a good practice to define a constant class with all dp's ?

Comment: From a performance standpoint, I would not worry about it. You might want to have centralized definitions of dimensions as part of a design system, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare Just curious we use `x.dp` in every `@Composable()` why doesn't it cause it any performance issue, as it create a new object everytime?

Comment: The cost is not going to be significant, IMHO, especially if you are good about minimizing unnecessary recompositions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No runtime performance impact.

`Dp` is a Kotlin [inline `value class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html). Behind the scenes it's just a `Float` with convenience functions, that looks like an object. The Kotlin compiler inlines all uses to just the `Float` value. (Note that this will have a *very* minor compilation-time impact.)

There's no object creation/boxing or garbage collection at runtime, just conversion/copy of the `Int` to a `Float`. (If the `Int` is a literal, the Kotlin compiler might optimize that conversion/copy away, doing the `Float` conversion at compile-time.)

When the `Dp` is used for sizing inside a `@Composable`, the actual pixel size will be computed by multiplying this `Float` by the screen density. That mutiplication is quick, but if you use the resulting pixel value in many places you may want to store it. (For example, if you're drawing in a `Canvas`)